# How do @everyone and @here work? What's the difference between them?

Tags: discord

How exactly do the **@everyone** and ***@here*** commands work in Discord?

I've learned from experience they're both used to send notifications to everyone in a Discord server. However, I've noticed that there are some servers where I can't use either command. Why is that? Also, is there any difference between the two commands?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

***@here*** notifies all non-idle users in the channel currently online.

***@everyone*** notifies all users in the channel, even if they are offline.

---

If you can't mention ***@everyone*** or ***@here*** in a channel, then the server owner likely hasn't given you permission to do so. Server owners can enable or disable the option for specific user roles in their server settings, and in their channel settings.

To set permissions on a server, click the small arrow next to the server name.

[image: Arrow to open server settings]

Open **Server Settings -> Roles**, then click a role to customize that role's permissions.

To set permissions on a channel/channel group, click the small arrow next to the channel name.

[image: Disabling @everyone for @everyone]

---

It's worth noting that users can suppress ***@everyone*** and ***@here*** notifications on a per-server basis in their notification settings. See [*How do I stop @everyone mentions from select servers?*](https://support.discordapp.com/hc/en-us/articles/215253148-How-do-I-stop-everyone-mentions-from-select-servers-) for more information.

[image: Checkbox to suppress @everyone and @here]

Comment: In practice I get notified whether I'm online or not. And it appears in my mentions when I log back on just the same. I see no functional difference

Comment: What do you mean by "@here notifies all non-idle users currently online." ? Did you mean just online I mean they are online anyway or can people idle offline? I don't understand the difference. And what if people are shown as offline but are actually online?

Comment: @TheDefinitionist People can set their status to idle or do not disturb. People with yellow status icons are idle.

Comment: What do you mean "It's worth noting that users can suppress **everyone** and **here** notifications on a **per-server/channel/channel-group basis**"? The link you used as a reference specifically states "That simple. Remember, the "Suppress **everyone** and **here** option functions on a **per-server basis**, so you can be selective about who you want to hear from depending on which server you're on."

Comment: @LWC Good catch. I've edited my answer.